# Include javascript file in sharepoint visual web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using sharepoint 2010 and developing a visual web part. I had javascript functions on the ascx file and they all used to work file.Now I have moved them to a single javascript.js file and deployed it to the _layouts folder on server.

And I have put the below line on the ascx file to reference to that file

```
<script src="/sites/xxxxx/_layouts/customwebparts/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

and then on the ascx.cs file and I am using the methods defined in this file for eg.,

```
      btnCancel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "{return Action(Cancel the form?)};");
```

But it is not working, it is not displaying the confimration box ...Am I referencing the wrong way. Please help me ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To reference a javascript file from within a SharePoint Visual Web Part you need to use the SharePoint:ScriptLink tag (example below):

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="<someid>" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/...<Path>"></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

I add a layouts mapped folder to my Visual Web Part project and place a scripts folder within the default folder, which I believe is the projects name.  Following this model ensures that the javascript file is always kept up-to-date during deployment.  The 'Name' property in the above tag is just the path to the javascript file relative to _layouts, so something like "/_layouts/ProjectName/Scripts/myjavascript.js".

As an FYI if you want to use CSS as well there is a SharePoint:CssRegistration tag as well.  I find these are the 2 that I use the most.

Comment: If the Javascript file is loaded on the Styles Libary , can you please let me know how do I include it on ascx file.<script src="/sitecollections/style library/customwebparts/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>  I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: Take a look at this link, I believe the 3rd code block has what you are looking for. http://surinder.computing-studio.com/post/2011/02/03/Reference-Custom-CSS-and-JavaScript-files-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx.  

<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Core Styles/jquery.js%>" runat="server" />

Comment: If you use F12 tools to debug the page that the Javascript is suppose to run on does indicate that the javascript is being reached?

Comment: with Sharepoint 2013 the path should be "/_layouts/15/ProjectName/Scripts/myjavascript.js"

Comment: ^ this comment brings up a point that came back to bite us during an upgrade to 2013. There are two paths to the layout folder after upgrading: 14 and 15. if you (in 2010) referenced using /_layouts, in 2013 that points to the 14 folder, To point it to the 15 folder you have to use /_layouts/15. I had to adjust permissions on the 14 layouts folder after the upgrade to avoid having to go back through all my web parts and change the folder reference to 15. the only reason I bring it up is if you will be upgrading to 2016, this could change again, effectively breaking your links.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your javascript file in the *Layout* mapped folder and use the `SharePoint:ScriptLink` tag:

```
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLink1" runat="server" Localizable="false" Name="some-layout-subfolder/file.js" />
```

If you have a **file not found error** you should check that the `Localizable` attribute is set to `false` and from **Visual Studio**, in the properties of the js file, `Build Action` should be set as `Content` and `Deployment Type` should be `TemplateFile`.

Check here for more details:
http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/06/19/include-javascript-and-css-files-in-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-web-part/